# input text width auto size with it's content

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Hello, i have table with lot of td, is it possible to autosize it's column depend on content length? `width: 100%` only autosize to it's td, not the content.

```
$('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function () {
    $(this).attr('size', this.value.length);
}).trigger('keyup');
```

i used this script, but it's not work when i add class `form-control` from bootstrap. when i remove `form-control` class it working like this

[image]

Comment: Can't you just set a css `min-width` and then increase the width depending on the input length. Also you should try not to change the UI to much as it can confuse the user

Comment: thankyou, already add `min-width`, but for some textbox i don't know how much i supposed to set `min-width`. so i hope i still can expand automatically this width based on user input, so no more text hidden because it's length not enough.. the problem is my script not working if i add class `form-control` from bootstrap